How to prove this function is convergeant in the domain, using Fourier series.
I'm given $f(x)=|x|$ in the domain $[-\pi, \pi]$ with $g(x)$ defined as follows:
$$g\left(x\right)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}-n\cdot a_{n}\sin\left(nx\right)$$
where $an$ is the Fourier coefficient of $f(x)$.
$$a_{n}=\begin{cases}
0 & n\ \text{is even}\\
-\frac{4}{\pi n^{2}} & n\ \text{is odd}
\end{cases}$$
I need to prove that $g(x)$ converges in that domain, and I don't know how to do so.
I do realize that the derivative of the Fourier series of $f(x)=|x|$ is exactly $g(x)$ but I'm not sure how it helps me, I've proved that $f$ converges uniformly in that domain and that $g$ is the derivative of $f$, but (from what I know) to show that $g(x)$ converges in that domain I need to prove uniform convergence which requires that $g$ will be continuous, and it's clearly not approaching something continuous, I feel like I'm missing some simple fact.
here's the series for $f(x)=|x|$:
$$\pi-\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{4\cdot\cos\left(\left(2k-1\right)x\right)}{\pi\left(2k-1\right)^{2}}$$

Why not to take just the function $h(x)=-1,x\in[-\pi,0)$ and $h(x)=1,x\in[0,\pi]$ and compute its Fourier series? You will find exactly your $g$. $h$ clearly satisfies Dirichlet's conditions, hence its Fourier series converges.
